# Using numbers in the application name

Tags: java, android, cordova, configuration

I'm building a Phonegap app whose name is entirely composed by numbers.

The iOS version of the app compiles properly, while compilation of the Android version fails because Phonegap creates a Java class with the same name as the application, and class names that start with a number are not allowed by the compiler.

I discovered out that it's possible to modify the `www/config.xml` file to change the `com.gabrielecirulli.[name]` identifier on the `<widget>` tag, and the `<name>` tag.

By appending a word to the application name, such as `app[numbers]`, the app compiles properly, but this has the following drawbacks:

- The application name on the Android home screen now appears as `app[numbers]` instead of the actual name, `[numbers]`.
- Changing these settings also influences the iOS build, by possibly changing the application name on the home screen and in other unpredictable places.

The former issue can be worked around by editing `platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml` and removing the prefix from the application name, and there might be a solution to the latter as well.

---

I would like to know if it's possible to reserve a special "internal" name for the app, so that it is compiled using that name to avoid compilation errors, but retains the official "public" name for any place visible by the end user, such as the application icon or other menus.